# Safari not displaying background images that are loaded from a web service

Tags: html, css, angularjs

We have an issue with a angularJS application where several background images are being loaded from a different server. We do this because depending on which user is accessing the site will depend on what branding image displays.

Everything looks great in all browsers except Safari where the background image will not display. I've exhausted every trick I know of so Im seeking support here hoping that maybe this issue has come up before. Here is a URL to the application:
http://newux.unicas.com/applicant-ux/#/login/

This is the css being used for the background image:

```
.cas-login-header .cas-org-logo, .cas-app-header .cas-org-logo {
   background-image: url('/applicant-ux/api/resources?image=OptomCAS.png');
   background-size: cover;
   height: 62px;
   width: 562px;
 }
```

angular code is:

```
$rootScope.setThemeCss = function(){
    var themeResource = resourceFactory.init({
        resourceUri: "/applicant-ux/api/css/themecss"
    });

    var retrieveHandler = function(response) {
        var header = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var previousStyle = document.getElementById('branding');
        if(previousStyle){
            header.removeChild(previousStyle);
        }

        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.innerHTML = response.data.css;
        style.id='branding';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
        Session.set("css",response.data.css);
    };

    pageContent.get(function() {
        return themeResource.retrieve();
    }).then(retrieveHandler);
};
```

Comment: It's not displaying on mobile safari?

Comment: The problem is with Safari browser on desktop

Comment: Problem solved. Safari doesn't allow special characters in the image path if it is a CSS style such as background url. Example: /applicant-ux/api/resources?image=OptomCAS.png. The fix was to append the image in an image tag instead of a style.